# Map data to tailwind grid specific layout

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, tailwind-css

I've been trying to reach this type of [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnYyO.jpg) using grid as I find it to be more easy to handle in situations as such. but it seems that my current code achieves stack two boxes on top of each other in the first column and only one in the second column which is not as the required layout. I would have liked it if the primary color which is in `index=0` of the array to be the div taking the entire first column and the two remaining elements of the array to be stacked on top of each other in the second column.

Here is how it currently looks : [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV3LB.jpg)

Here is my current component code along with tailwind classes:

```
const ColorPreview = ({ colors }: any) => {
  console.log('colors inside colorPreview', colors);

  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-2 gap-6'>
      {Object.keys(colors).map((key, index) => (
        <div key={uuidv4()} className=' overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-2'>
          <div
            className={clsx(
              'h-[6rem] w-20 p-4',
              index === 0 && 'h-60 w-48 p-4',
            )}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: colors[key],
            }}
          >
            {' '}
          </div>
          <p className='justify-center p-2 text-base'>{colors[key]}</p>
          {/* primary or secondary or tertiary*/}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about React, but this type of layout could be created in a such manner - create not two columns but three (or even more), where the first elements spans on 2 columns which gives you 2:1 proportion. Same thing for the rows. See [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Cowy9943bN)

Answer (score 1):

I write a css class. this will work if you had only 3 items.

```
.parentClass {
  /* targeting only those children 3n+1 */
  /* n=0=>1st, n=1=>4th and so on */
  & > *:nth-child(3n + 1),
    // in large screen make the first item col span 2 units and row spans 2 units
    @screen lg {
      @apply col-span-2 row-span-2;
    }
  }
```

If you have more items, and decide which one you want to target. Here is a link about nth child:
https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Based on your layout decision you might write 2 separate logic. for example

```
& > *:nth-child(3n + 1),
& > *:nth-child(6n + 1) {
   /* apply this css to target children. you could add more css here */
   @screen lg {
        @apply col-span-2 row-span-2;
    }
```

then apply the `parentClass` class name to the top-level div.